# Matplotlib : Overlay of JPEG and plot_wireframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib

On stackoverflow one can find answers to questions on how to overlay e.g. a JPEG picture with 2D matplotlib graphics. My question is whether this is also possible with 3D matplotlib graphics, e.g. the result of plot_wireframe? For instance, as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.io import wavfile 

format='jpg' 
frame=0

phi, x = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:50j, 0:200:100j]
r = np.ones( 100 )

y=r * np.cos( phi )
z=r * np.sin( phi )

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)
im = plt.imread( 'abc.jpg' )
ax.imshow(im, extent = [ 6, 7, 6, 7 ] )

ax.view_init(azim=300,elev=20)

ax.set_xlim([0,200])    
ax.set_ylim([-2,2]) 
ax.set_zlim([-2,2]) 

ax.set_xlabel( 'Time axis' )
ax.set_ylabel( 'I axis' )
ax.set_zlabel( 'Q axis' )

plt.show()
```

The idea is that the 3D plot is a cilinder. Actually, initially the radius of this cilinder will vary over its length. The abc.jpg picture will be an iron, that is placed alongside the cilinder. In an outer shell script, the frame index is looped over a range, and as function of this frame index, the iron will be at a different position alongside the cilinder. The outer shell script, e.g. using ffmpeg, will convert the series of 3D plots with the iron into an mp4 file, in which the iron "is ironing" the cilinder. ( The script above does not mention that the cilinder for small frame index has a varying radius, and for the final frame index value in the frame index range will have a flat surface. Like this the iron is ironing the cilinder, to be flat in the end. )

Any hints are greatly appreciated

( PS. I also tried doing this in mayavi. Then the difficulty is that mayavi normalizes the average value of the radius along the length of the cilinder, and also the standard deviation of the radius of the cillinder along the length of the cilinder. Like this it turned out to be hard to control the relative content of the DC and AC component of the radius with mayavi.)

The matplotlib script above, when the 'imshow' command is included neither shows the proper 3D plot of the cilinder, nor the abc.jpg picture. It does show the 3D axis.

Comment: What is the result you want? Can you give an example of a plot you would like to recreate?

Comment: Hi Will, I extended the formulation of the question. As I dont have 10 reputation, I cannot post pictures.

Comment: Put links to pictures in. I, or someone else if they get there first, will edit in images.

Comment: I had a look, you can do it using the code in [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo3.html), but it was very slow. It might not be a problem if you just want to get individual frames. I'll have another look. Could you include a link to `abc.png`?